# I want to implement a 2d regular google map on a unity project for both android and ios

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, unity-game-engine

I want to implement a google map screen and plot static location markers on specific latitude longitude points.This has to be done exclusively on a unity project so i can run it on both Android and iOS.

I am new to unity but I know how to do this on Android , so I hope it isn't that different from it.

Any help would be appreciated on how I can get started.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Google Maps, you'll need to register with Google for an API key. You'll then have to make an HTTP request to the Google API.

The [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) will return an image, which you'll have to turn into a texture, and then a material, and then add it to a quad for 3d use, or a sprite for 2d use.

If you do not want to go through that process with Google there are other free online API for maps and satellite pictures.

Comment: Hi, Louis. What about in case I need to zoom & move functionality for the map? Using the Static Maps API, I was able to place the static map into unity, but I am not sure how to zoom and move it.

Comment: You can either move and scale the texture, or request another image, or both (move the image leaving an empty area, which will be filled when the new image is loaded). If you do too much requests though, Google may slow down your connection. You should probably implement a more complex Maps API/SDK that handles this for you, but you need to look it up. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/gaming/overview_musk